# Word Document SaveAs2 in Format wdFormatDocument97

Tags: c#, ms-word, interop, document, save-as

I'm using Microsoft Interop Word version 15.0.0.0 in order to create a new Word document, insert some text into it, and save it.

When I'm saving it using the following command:

```
document.SaveAs2(wordFilePath);
```

the document is saved in format DOCX.

But when I'm saving it using the following command:

```
document.SaveAs2(wordFilePath, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatDocument97);
```

the document is seemingly saved as Word-97 DOC (Windows explorer display it with Word-97 DOC icon and type), but it is really internally saved as DOCX (I can see this in two ways: it has the same size of the corresponding DOCX, and when I open it with Word-2016 and select SaveAs, the default save format is DOCX!).

How can I save a document in real document-97 format?

Here's the function used to create a new Word document, whose type depends on the extension (DOC vs. DOCX) of given file path:

```
public static void TextToMsWordDocument(string body, string wordFilePath)
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application winword = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
    winword.Visible = false;
    object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document document = winword.Documents.Add(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
    if (body != null)
    {
        document.Content.SetRange(0, 0);
        document.Content.Text = (body + System.Environment.NewLine);
    }
    if (System.IO.Path.GetExtension(wordFilePath).ToLower() == "doc")
        document.SaveAs2(wordFilePath, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatDocument97);
    else // Assuming a "docx" extension:
        document.SaveAs2(wordFilePath);
    document.Close(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
    document = null;
    winword.Quit(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
    winword = null;
}
```

And here's the code used to call this function:

```
TextToMsWordDocument("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", "text.doc");
TextToMsWordDocument("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", "text.docx");
```

Comment: I tried to replicate this with a document-based add-in, but it did not show the same symptoms you mention, and the zip structure is quite different from the docx format. You may need to post a minimal, complete, verifiable example. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Also which version of Word? I tested in 2010.

Comment: @Chris: I'm using Word-2016, and Interop.Word version 15.0.0.0. Added these details and a short version of my code in my question. Thanks.

Comment: I can replicate it with that code targeting both 14.0 and 15.0. But I'm not sure why it doesn't work, while similar code in a document add-in does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a rather stupid error...compare ‘ == ".doc" ’ instead of ‘ == "doc"...

I didn't notice it due to the fact that when SaveAs2 received a file path with extension ".doc" and no WdSaveFormat, it - strangely enough- created a Word document file that had the problem I explained here...